# How to send scheduled emails from odoo 10?

Tags: odoo-10, erp

We have a wordpress website the allow user to download a software installer for trial by giving their email address.

Upon download, we will receive a email notification from our wordpress website. So for the next few weeks, we will manually send emails (containing tutorials and useful information) to the person who download our software.

I would like to automate this scheduled email sending.
I was thinking of doing it using odoo 10.
Is this possible in odoo 10? 
If so, How and where do I start?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible in Odoo. You need to follow the following steps.

1. Create a Email template in Odoo
2. Create a scheduler(cron job) using python function
3. Call the Email template and trigger the Email from the Python function based on the time interval

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Can you also tell me how to trigger the start of a series of email sending from the lead generated?

Let's say a lead is created in my odoo CRM, how do I create an automation that will send a series of email 1 day, 3 days , 1 week, 1 month from now ?

Answer (score 3):

Creating a Scheduler. This will create a scheduler view. You can see this under settings -> Automation -> scheduled action

```xml
        <record id="ir_send_mail_cron_scheduler_action" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Followup Mail scheduler</field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">days</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
            <field eval="'crm.lead'" name="model"/>
            <field eval="'send_followup_mail'" name="function"/>
        </record>
```

In `crm.lead` object you need to create a function from which you can call the template. Before that, you have a one2many field where you have your email templates attached so that you can take email templates from that.

```py
@api.multi
def send_followup_mail(self):
    # write your logic to find the time intervals(day 1, day 2, week)
    # based on the time interval trigger the mails.
    # use a loop to get the mail template id from the one2many
    mail_template = self.env['mail.template'].browse(template_id)
    mail_template.write({'email_to': self.email})

    #this will trigger the mail
    if mail_template:
       mail_template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=True)
```

Comment: Hi, after adding this method to a module, I get the following error (in odoo12) when I try to run the automated task: (Document type: Message, Operation: read) (Records :[32], User : 2), Q: did you have to add some security rule to make this work?, thanks in advance for the help, nice code :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Mail Template, it also has a char field called "scheduled_date" to which you can add python code e.g. 
`${(datetime.datetime.now() + relativedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}`

This means that the email created from this template will be sent 3 days later..

The ${} are for the jinja templating engine